# Using InStr to compare two String but failed

Tags: excel, vba

My object is to fill a quality control table. In this table I have already all the test points, and my work is to look at the point and search in another sheet for the correct answer, and fill the blank cell. For example:

```
TV1 | Coulor
TV1 | Size
TV2 | Coulor
TV2 | Size
TV3 | Coulor
TV3 | Size
```

And in the other sheet, I've already the result of a new report :

```
TV1 | Coulor : red   | Size : 1
TV2 | Coulor :blue   | Size : 1
TV3 | Coulor : green | Size : yellow
```

Well the example is simplified, in the real report I still have more details, but generally, it's the same. Here's my Sub:

```
Private Sub FillTarget(ByVal TargetSheet As String, ByVal DepositSheet As String, _
    ByVal DataRow As Integer, ByVal DataColumn As Integer, _
    ByVal DepositRow As Integer, ByVal DepositColumn As Integer)

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
Dim OpenedFile As String, myObject As String

Dim MarkRow As Integer
MarkRow = 1
Dim myData As String
Dim EndSearch As Boolean

Dim TargetCell As Range
Dim TargetTag As Range
Dim TargetType As Range
Dim TargetZone As Range
Dim TargetTest As Range

Dim DepositTag As Range
Dim DepositZone As Range
Dim DepositResult As Range

'for every line in the report    
For i = 8 To DataRow
With Worksheets(TargetSheet)
    Set TargetCell = .Cells(i, DataColumn)
    Set TargetTag = .Cells(i, 15)
    Set TargetType = .Cells(i, 17)
    Set TargetZone = .Cells(i, 18)
    Set TargetTest = .Cells(i, 20)
End With
myObject = TargetTag.Text + "_" + TargetType.Text

'search every line in result sheet
For j = MarkRow To DepositRow
    With Worksheets(DepositSheet)
        Set DepositTag = .Cells(j, 1)
        Set DepositZone = .Cells(j, 2)
    End With
    'if the product is right
    If InStr(DepositTag.Value, myObject) <> 0 Then
        OpenedFile = OpenedFile & DepositTag.Text & "|"
        'if the zone is right
        If InStr(DepositZone.Value, TargetZone.Value + ":") <> 0 _  '<===Here's the problem
            Or InStr(TargetZone.Text, "/") <> 0 Then
            'for each cell in this line
            For k = 2 To DepositColumn
                With Worksheets(DepositSheet)
                    Set DepositResult = .Cells(j, k)
                End With
                'find the correct test (colour, siez etc)
                If InStr(DepositResult.Value, TargetTest.Value) <> 0 Then
                    MarkRow = j
                    myData = DepositResult.Text
                    TargetCell.Value = myData
                    EndSearch = True
                    Exit For
                End If

            Next k

        End If

    End If

    If EndSearch Then Exit For
Next j

EndSearch = False
Next i

End Sub
```

I've used F8 to run, and found that the first compare of InStr `If InStr(DepositTag.Value, myObject) <> 0` works, but the second time `If InStr(DepositZone.Value, TargetZone.Value + ":") <> 0` it's stopped, even if there is already a string inside, but it seems that it can not figure out wether there are the same part in these two strings.

And I've tried to use the 'stupid' way, just don't use set and `If InStr(Sheets("Brouillon").Cells(j, 2).Text, Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 18).Text) <> 0` works. I didn't figure out where's the problem.

So if you've got some idea, please leave a note. Thank you!

Comment: did you step through line-by-line and observe the variable values to see why it's not working. It's impossible for us to test without a full sample data set.

Comment: Sorry for this delay, and I've just tested the program with the 'stupid' method. If I change `If InStr(DepositZone.Value, TargetZone.Value + ":") <> 0` into `If InStr(Sheets("Brouillon").Cells(j, 2).Text, Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 18).Text) <> 0`, just don't use the `Set`, and it works. I don't know where is the problem.

Comment: I've left it be and continue to work on the other parts, and when I came back to this bug, it just works... It's really weird. But thank you anyway!